# Кто знает, как устроен вывод сообщения в Title страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Например, как это устроено в социальной сети Одноклассники. Когда приходит новое сообщение, в заголовке страницы пишется "Новое сообщение(2)"

Comment: Поспешил, не подумал сам...
Вот тут тоже решение есть:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601163/jquery-change-pages-title-when-user-in-a-different-tab

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.title = 'Новое сообщение'